# Cloud Endpoints Collection Parameter

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Im using Google App Engine Cloud Endpoints and Im trying to receive a collection parameter .
Not sure if I can do this. I know I can return a List or any Collection.

This:

```
   public List<Pair> initializationSetup(Pair pPair){}
```

Works fine, but If I try to receive a list of pairs, the .api file is not created.

```
   public List<Pair> initializationSetup(List<Pair> pPairs){
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you want the resulting REST request to look like? A `GET` request like `?pPairs=abc&pPairs=def&pPairs=ghi` or a `POST` request that takes something like `{"pPairs":["abc","def","ghi"]}` in the request body?

Comment: @Jason Hall, why exactly does this matter? What are you getting at?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cloud Endpoints only deals with classes having the bean standard.

So, I created a new class named ObjectListContainer:

```
public class ObjectListContainer {
    public List<Object> getObjectsList() {
        return ObjectsList;
    }
    public void setObjectsList(List<Object> objectsList) {
        ObjectsList = objectsList;
    }
    private List<Object> ObjectsList;
}
```

Same problem if you are trying to return a String, you can't. You have to make a StringContainer.

Comment: I think you can use `@javax.inject.Named` annotation for `String`s. See [Endpoints doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#named).

Comment: You can use `String`s as parameters (with @Named, as you said) but cannot return them, as @davidbq said.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a similar solution after think during long hours . 
Try this:

```
public class JsonList<T> { 
private List<T> listItens;

public List<T> getListItens() {
    return listItens;
}

public void setListItens(List<T> listItens) {
    this.listItens = listItens;
}}
```

and in your method:

```
@ApiMethod(
        name = "name",
        path = "path",
        httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST)
public CollectionResponse<Information> getInformation(JsonList<String> listOfItens) {}
```