# Cloud Endpoints Collection Parameter and "operating on too many entity groups in a single transaction"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I need pass a collection of objects as Google Cloud endpoint api paramter. There is a way to do that: [encapsulate the list into another object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763061/cloud-endpoints-collection-parameter) .  Then there is cross group issue, so I [explicitly enable it in persistence.xml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions#Using_Transactions) . But then there is another problem: I need upload hundreds objects and there is only up to [5 items](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions) if doing cross group transaction.

So how I'm able to solve the original problem ( upload collection of hundreds objects as google cloud endpoint api parameter) under these restrictions? Thanks.

Comment: i also search for the solution but still cant find good one except u do it in different transaction for every 5 items.

Comment: it's sad. I'm wondering if the com.google.api.server.spi.response.CollectionResponse is the possible solution? It does support download a collection with hundreds objects.but how to wire it for upload is a question...

Comment: Can you pull apart your question a bit? Are you trying to write hundreds of objects in a single transaction? Is this a requirement, or is it acceptable to write the objects independently (either as part of a single request or several)?

Comment: Thanks Dan, actually the object is not big, one type of them is just List<String>,  to pass the a lot of objects' Id to the api as the parameter. Yes, I can do them separately but it's really inefficient if I have to call the same API several hundreds times. Because it's already possible to download a lot of objects in one api call by using CollectionResponse, I really like to know if it's possible to use it to pass the collection as api parameters too...

Comment: I tried to just use the standard api, insert one object each api call. because I need upload a lot of them at a short time, I got the error  code "Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: too much contention on these datastore entities. please try again."

Comment: catch the ConcurrentModificationException to persistent the object again. it works! but it's a reliable way to avoid the ConcurrentModificationException? Thanks.