# Cloud Endpoint parameter should not be named

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-endpoints

I want send a `HashMap<String, String>` from JS application to my Google App. I created a `HashMapContainer` class such as in : [Cloud Endpoints Collection Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763061/cloud-endpoints-collection-parameter).

The Endpoint method is defined like this :

```
public Entity myMethod(
        @Named('param1') String param1, 
        @Nullable @Named('param2') HashMapContainer param2) {
    //...
}
```

When I run the API generation this error happens :

```
com.google.api.server.spi.config.validation.ApiConfigInvalidException: 
    Resource type 'class com.mason.server.entity.HashMapContainer' 
    in method 'endpoint.myMethod' should not be named.
```

Therefore, I remove the `@Named` annotation. The API is generated but obviously, I do not receive the parameter send by the JS application. My JavaScript is like this :

```
function doTransaction() {
    var req = gapi.client.myApi.endpoint.myMethod({
        'param1': 'FOO',
        'param2': {
            'value1':'foofoo',
            'value2':'barbar',
            'value3':'foobar'
        }
    });
    req.execute(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

How I can get the `param2` if I'm not allowed to use the `@Named` annotation ?
Maybe my JavaScript is wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Cloud Enpoints [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations) says:

> ***@Named:*** This annotation indicates the name of the parameter in the
>   request that gets injected here. A parameter that is not annotated
>   with @Named is injected with the whole request object.

Basically, as far as I understand, when you add `@Named` annotation, the parameters will be included at the end of the request URL:

```
http://end_point_url?parameter1=xxx&parameter2=yyy
```

Obviously the parameter types that support `@Named` annotation are only a few (int, long, String, Boolean and their correspondent arrays, I think), because you can't append a whole hashmap to the request URL!

On the other hand, if you don't use `@Named`, the parameter will be included (*injected*) within the POST data.

In order to send a parameter within the HTTP body using the Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript, you just have to include that parameter into an object called `resource` inside the JSON-RPC request, like this:

```
var req = gapi.client.myApi.endpoint.myMethod({
    'param1': 'FOO',
    'resource': {
        'param2': {
            'value1':'foofoo',
            'value2':'barbar',
            'value3':'foobar'
        }
    }
});
```

The API client will automatically send `param1` in the URL and `param2` in the POST data...

This is explained in detail in [**this section**](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/dev/dev_jscript#Buildingandexecutingtherequest) of the Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript documentation.

Comment: I've been banging my head against the wall trying to get this to work for the past three hours as your solution didn't work. I ended up getting it to work by doing this:  
    `var req = gapi.client.myApi.endpoint.myMethod({  
        'param1': 'FOO',
        'value1': 'foofoo'
        'value2': 'barbar'
    });`
Which makes no sense, but works. Any idea why your solution didn't work for me and this does?

Answer (score 2):

Using HashMap would get all the parameters passed to the Api Method, what i will advise is you use **`HaspMap<String,Object>`** as param2 map type,
 then this notifies us that inside this hashmap we can have our param2 as key of the hashmap. Then we can type cast the value of the param key to HashMap then we can loop through it like as if is the normal initial hashMap passed initially.

```
HashMap <String,String> mapR = (HashMap <String,String>) param2.get("param2");

        for(Map.Entry<String,String> x:mapR.entrySet()){
            log.log(Level.INFO,x.getKey()+","+x.getVaue());

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The example in [This doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/parameter-and-return-types#query_parameters) shows the annotations used in a different order from what your code shows.

> public Resource get(@Named("id") @Nullable int id) { … }

So according to this, your

`@Nullable @Named('param2') HashMapContainer param2) {`

should become

```
@Named('param2') @Nullable HashMapContainer param2) {
```

I tested it out both ways - only the latter seems to work for me.

Comment: Hi, in fact I had do not use the annotation `@named` and all parameters without name are received as a HashMap. I'll write an answer for explaining this.

Answer (score 1):

From the day I have asked this question, I found *"another way"* to use [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/). By following the documentation it's really simple to figure out how we can send an HashMap (Object in fact) from a JavaScript script.

Definition [Endpoints/annotations#named](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#named)

> The @Named annotation is required **for all non-entity type parameters** passed to server-side methods. This annotation indicates the name of the parameter in the request that gets injected here. **A parameter that is not annotated with @Named is injected with the whole request object**.

#### JavaScript

We send a JS object through the REST API.

```
function doSomething() {
    var req = gapi.client.myApi.myMethod({
        'param1': 'FOO',
        'value1': 'foofoo',
        'value2': 'barbar',
        'value3': 'foobar'
    });
    req.execute(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

#### Java API

And we receive all non-annotated parameters in the Java Map. They are sent in the HTTP request body (like describe in the documentation).

```
public Entity myMethod(
    @Named('param1') String param1, 
    Map<String, Object> param2) {

    System.out.println(param1); // FOO
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(param2.get("value1"))); // foofoo
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(param2.get("value2"))); // barbar
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(param2.get("value3"))); // foobar

    //...
}
```

*Note the name "param2" does not matter for the client side, it could be named "resources".*

This example is not the best practice but the simplest way to send parameters in the request and data into the body. You can improve it using your own class (instead of the Java Map interface) and add [@ApiTransformer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#apitransformer) if needed. If you are using an entity as parameter, ensure of the annotations order (`@named` must be the first one).