# Google endpoints

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a specific question about retrieving a query from an Endpoints model method in Python.

```
    # DataPointModel GET LIST api method
    @DataPointModel.query_method(query_fields=('user_key', ), # Fields from which the   method is querying from
                                 path='datapoint/list/{user_key}', # REST api parameters
                                 name='datapoint.list_get_by_user_key') # Metod name
    def datapoint_list_get_by_user_key(self, query):
        '''
        Returns the DataPointModel object model list by its user KEY
        '''
        return query
```

And I have the client side on Android (Java).
The problem is that this returns a DataPointModelCollection which doesn't contain a 
List (dataPointsCollection.getDatapointList() this is null).

The DataPointModelCollection contains "items" therefore it contains the right objects,
if printed toString() and is shown as JSON. However the problem still remains, because
I would like to map the retrieved DataPointModelCollection as a List of Java objects DataPointModel.

I would really love to hear some insights about this. What troubles me is that I can upload a DataPointModelCollection where I set a List to it... but it just 
doesn't work the other way around ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already figured it out - DataPointModelCollection should have a different name, because endpoints somehow has a default reserved name for each model collection. So I just changed the name of the model and it worked, to DataPointModelInsertCollection

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 2**: Sorry, I still didn't understand what you are asking. This is the actual answer - only read the other sections for interest.

[This docs page](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/google-cloud-endpoints-for-android/#h.mvx1eqsso26q) explains how you can extract the entities that are in your client-side Android "-Collection" generated class. You need to call `.getItems()`, not a named function like "getDatapointList()". Under "About Supported Return Types":

> **Lists of serializable types** Actually, what Endpoints generates is a new “Collection” JSON class that is similar to every other client
>   model class. For example, if you have an object in your model that is
>   represented by Lobster.java, and you want to return a List,
>   the library will have a LobsterCollection.java. You can retrieve the
>   list of Lobsters in your client by calling getItems().

---

**EDIT**: terribly sorry, I admit I skimmed your question and my brain parsed java. Python answer first:

**PYTHON**

You should become familiar with [Message](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/messages/messageclass) objects and their [Fields](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/messages/fieldclasses). You cannot simply return a python object. Message objects contain multiple Field values that are used to translate the object into a JSON object for transfer over the API HTTP request.

To return a Message object from your Endpoints function that has a list of multiple Message objects (each of which wraps a StringField and a DateTimeField, for example), the Message class defining the this return type should have a [MessageField](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/messages/messagefieldclass) in it, which allows you to put Messages (such as the type we created that contains a StringField and a DateTimeField) inside other Messages (our return type). In addition, on this field, you will need to set `repeated=True`, as you can see in the following snippet:

```
# REPEATED IN MESSAGE FIELD IN ORDER CLASS
class Lot(messages.Message):
    price = messages.IntegerField(1, required=True)
    quantity = messages.IntegerField(2, required=True)

class Order(messages.Message):
    symbol = messages.StringField(1, required=True)
    total_quantity = messages.IntegerField(2, required=True)
    trade_type = messages.EnumField(TradeType, 3, required=True)
    lots = messages.MessageField(Lot, 4, repeated=True) # REPEATED FIELD!
    limit = messages.IntegerField(5)
```

---

**JAVA**

You need to implement a wrapper class that contains a collection. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15008004/4270992).

Read [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types#return_types_and_request_body_types) for more info on parameter and return types.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15457490/4270992) for an interesting answer that explains how to add multiple entity types as parameters (the short story: can't do multiple parameters of entity type, can't do Collections of entity type, need to use a wrapper entity that contains two entities)

Comment: I tried to avoid doing stuff with message class, because endpoints_proto_datastore lib enables model method queries http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/